# Does Kogito support asynchronous business rule/service task execution?

Tags: kogito

Does Kogito support asynchronous execution of business rule/service task if marked as `async = true` in BPMN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently async is not supported in kogito processes runtime, so basically if you set the `async` property in the editor is not considered by the runtime.
We have it tracked and still investigating to incorporate the feature in the next releases, once it is done it will be announced in the release notes as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Great news ... kogito version 1.15.0 comes with asyncronous functionality implementation. (https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single/#_kogito_async_execution_support_for_process_nodes)